# Realtime report in power BI

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-sql-database, kibana, powerbi

Is it possible to make real-time monitoring report by using Power BI?

I have an experience only with elasticsearch+kibana and I want to make the same dashboard by using Power BI:

1. There is a data source - RequestDateTime, Sendor, IsSuccess, RequestType, Request, Response. For example:

2016-10-20 12:00:12 | Test 1 | True  | SetUserInfo | xml here... | xml here...
2016-10-20 12:00:18 | Test 2 | False | GetUserInfo | xml here... |

2. This data can be downloaded from Azure SQL database, by using simple sql-query.
3. I want to make a simple column chart. X-axis should be a timeline, accoring to the RequestDateTime field. Y-axis should be a count of records, that is correspond to filters.
4. Report should have a filters by sendor, isSuccess, RequestType and RequestDateTime range (for example - last 6 hours).
5. The report should be able to be refreshed in a real-time mode, according to the new events in the database.

Comment: If you set up your report using DirectQuery, you can do that. I don't think there's an autorefresh yet though, but refreshing your report will relaunch those queries. No data is actually stored online, in comparison to the import option.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically aggregate data accoring to the timeline, like Kibana can do? And it is possible to use custom filters, that can be set by dashboard user or I have to make a several query for that?

Comment: I have no experience with Kibana but if you want to use timeline functions the easiest way would be to create a time dimension you can link with. Custom filters are basic functionality of PowerBI and can be set on the individual reports. Currently the only way to include filters on a Dashboard would be to pin a live report page. Pinning individual elements will not allow for an interactive experience. PowerBI is free to try, so if you have the time I'd just jump in and have a looksy.

Comment: Point 5 is possible in some scenario's. See https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/real-time-in-no-time-with-power-bi/. Section *The Power BI real-time streaming API* is interesting. You have to push new records to the API and then it will appear live on the dashboard. Since you have a sql database as datasource this could be challenging though

Comment: @PeterBons I'm aware of the streaming datasets, but i doubt these will provide the answer OP seeks. To my experience the streamed data is only stored a limited amount of time and will not allow aggregation of old data. The examples i've seen it's used for monitoring/visualising temperatures, machine cycles,... without the need for any long term analysis. The API just pushes new data and that's the data you'll be using. In addition the streaming datasets currently still have very limited reporting functionalities. I don't think filtering is one of those as of today.

Comment: @Jens filtering is possible for real-time dashboards. See https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Timeline-graph-for-Stream-Analytics-for-the-past-one-hour/m-p/7834 . I myself would create to solutions. One for live dashboarding using the Api and one for longterm analysis using sql database.

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline I usually do in my work using app.powerbi for real time visualization is :

1. Create a dataset: In your workspace, select the "create" option, there you can import or connect to data from Files and Databases. You can choose Azure SQL database and follow instructions.
2. Create a report: In your dataset list, select the icon to create a report (here you define the filters that you want) and save it.
3. Create a dashboard: Pin the charts to a dashboard. I have found that only dashboard refresh itself when data is added or deleted in the database, thus, you can see the real time in the dashboard.

You may find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSaBFf3ziUk) useful.